# Filter array of arrays with an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, select

Looking for a more efficient way of filtering an array of arrays using another array in Ruby. Let me demonstrate. Starting with this:

```
core = [[1, "apple", "James Bond"],
        [5, "orange", "Thor"],
        [10, "banana", "Wolverine"],
        [15, "orange", "Batman"],
        [20, "apple", "Mickey Mouse"],
        [25, "orange", "Lee Adama"],
        [30, "banana", "Luke Skywalker"]]

filter = ["apple", "banana"]

result = core.magical_function(filter)

# result == [[5, "orange", "Thor"],
#            [15, "orange", "Batman"],
#            [25, "orange", "Lee Adama"]]
```

The only thing I can think of is looping through the filter elements, but this slows down my code a lot when this toy example gets more complicated.

Comment: The most efficient way to filter an array of arrays is to not start with an array of arrays to begin with. A hash with your second column as keys would be the fastest way to process it. Can you construct such a hash instead?

Comment: What was your inefficient way?

Comment: @MarkThomas It would probably be more annoying to do it that way. This is a simplified example to demonstrate what I need. Converting to a hash would be really tough.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I looped through each element of the filter criteria and rejected the array element if core[x][1] == i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) and [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
core.reject { |_,fruit,_| filter.include?(fruit) }
  # => [[5, "orange", "Thor"], [15, "orange", "Batman"], [25, "orange", "Lee Adama"]]
```

If `filter` is large, first convert it to a set for faster lookups:

```
require 'set'
filter_set = filter.to_set
core.reject { |_,fruit,_| filter_set.include?(fruit) }
```

See [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) and its instance methods. When `require`d, set adds the instance method `to_set` to the module `Enumerable` which is `inclued`ed by `Array`. Ruby implements sets with unseen hashes.

Comment: i always forget about set :(

Answer (score 3):

You can change the filter array to a hash for faster look up. Then the whole thing requires just a single iteration through the core array:

```
filters = ["apple", "banana"].each_with_object({}) do |term, obj|
  obj[term] = true
end
# filters == {"apple" => true, "banana" => true}

filtered = core.reject do |array|
  filters[array[1]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `intersection` operator `&` ?

```
core.reject { |k| (k & filter).empty? }
```